# IBM Cloud / Bluemix Webhooks

Tags: ibm-cloud, webhooks

I have a cloud foundry instance hosted on IBM Cloud (formerly Bluemix). A third party vendor requires a url to publish webhooks onto my app. If I use the bluemix generated base url it works fine but if its a custom route (with my own domain) bluemix doesn't pass it on to the app.

Why is this happening and whats the solution (to be able to use custom domains)?

Comment: Add code and details

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be an SSL CA certificate issue.

Resolution was to grab a g2_bundle.crt file (with root cert in it from GoDaddy as my original cert was bought from them), upload to IBM Cloud certificate manager (found in the catalog) and viola :)!